# MySQL security concern

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Uh oh. I've just realized, I think it would be extremely easy to get into my MySQL database. My webserver uses a separate PHP script to connect to the server, which includes the username and password. Correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't someone easily require this file in their script and then have full access to my database?

Comment: If someone calls your PHP file the server (should) send them the parsed contents, not the source.

Comment: in less time you took to type this, you cold of just checked, by using 'view source' in your browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, when another server includes your file, the server will parse it, so all they will get is the parsed file unless things are not configured correctly.

However, you should not be storing your database login credentials within your web root for this very reason. If, for example, your web root is

```
/home/username/public_html/
```

then store the file in:

```
/home/username/db.inc.php // change file name accordingly
```

Then in your script, just do

```
require_once('/home/username/db.inc.php');
```

There is no way that someone can even access that file from HTTP because it is outside your web root.

Comment: Whoops. So I am in trouble then, if my file is inside my web root?

Comment: No, you're probably not in trouble, but it's good practice to keep any files that contain highly sensitive information, like your database login, outside the web root.

Answer (score 6):

No.

The source of your PHP script is never displayed to end users as long as your webserver is interpreting the file as a PHP script.

It is common to have db credentials in plain text in PHP files.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I honestly wasn't sure, but I just wanted to verify that the security wouldn't be at risk. I'll mark your answer as accepted as soon as SO lets me. :P

Comment: If you massively misconfigure your server you might allow `.phps` mode that can view source. There have also been [bugs that expose source code](http://www.infoworld.com/t/application-security/critical-php-vulnerability-exposes-servers-data-theft-or-worse-192428) in the past, so be absolutely certain you're patched and up to date.